# HTML Form email via post through PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

**EDIT: My Mail does get sent, but it does not send the FORM information, just the text I have placed. So this isn't an e-mail issue, its an issue of getting the Data attached to the email. I have not seen this question before.**

I'm not the best at PHP but I've been following a few guides on the internet, just learning some PHP. I've created a form in HTML that I want emailed to me upon submission. This is the code I have.

I am receiving an e-mail but the form input is not getting sent to me. Could someone please assist me. I've tried validating my code and it all seems right, and I don't see any flaws in my logic. Any help would be strongly appreciated.

```
<?php

//Creating Variables with data obtained from FORM on Previous Page

$firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
$date = $_POST['Date'];
$pick_up_time = $_POST['Time'];
$vehicle = $_POST['Fleet'];
$passenger = $_POST['Passengers'];
$l_bags = $_POST['LargeBags'];
$s_bags = $_POST['SmallBags'];
$phone_number = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
$e_mail = $_POST['eMail'];
$comments = $_POST['Comments'];

//Testing to see if variable is getting created

if ($firstname == "Reiyyan") {

print ("Welcome back, friend!");

}
else {

print ("MISSING DATA");

}




$email_from = 'reiyyan@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "New Message Test";
$email_body = "You got mail, here are the details. \n $firstname \n $lastname \n $date \n $pick_up_time \n $vehicle \n $passenger \n $l_bags \n $s_bags \n $phone_number \n $e_mail \n $comments".;

$to = "reiyyan@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//send mail
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done

?>
```

Here is my HTML Form

```
<form id="RequestCar" method="post" action="emailForm.php" enctype="text/plain">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required/> 
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" required />
     <br /><br />

    Date: <input type="date" name="Date" placeholder="01/01/2017" required />
    Pickup Time: <input type="time" name="Time" placeholder="12:00 PM" required />
    <br /><br />

    Vehicle:
    <select name="Fleet">
        <option value="No Preference">No Preference</option>
        <option value="LuxurySedan">Luxury Sedan</option>
        <option value="SUV">Sub Utility Vehicle (SUV)</option>
        <option value="Minivan">Minivan</option>
        <option value="Minivan">Stretch Limousine</option>
        <option value="Minivan">SUV Limousine</option>
        <option value="Minivan">Hummer Limousine</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    # of Passengers: <input type="number" name="Passengers" required min="1" />
    # of Large Bags: <input type="number" name="LargeBags"  />
    # of Small Bags: <input type="number" name="SmallBags"  />
    <br /><br />

    Phone Number: <input type="tel" name="PhoneNumber" required />
    eMail: <input type="email" name="eMail" required />
    <br /><br />

    Additional Comments
    <br /><br />
    <textarea rows="6" cols="100" name="Comments" form="RequestCar" placeholder="Enter Text Here..."></textarea>

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Regardless of what I try, I keep getting "MISSING DATA". It seems like the Form isn't passing on the variables to the php page.

Edit: This is hosted on GoDaddy, LINUX Server.

Comment: you have some odd mark up on the `$email_body`. Is that what your actual code is, or was that a copy/paste(/edit) error here on SO? (1) the `\`` in `\n \`$lastname`, and (2)  the `.\`` at the end (instead of a `;`)

Comment: This was a copy/paste error, the actual code does not have the odd mark up and I just fixed the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Change form action get to post

```
<form id="RequestCar" method="POST" action="emailForm.php" enctype="text/plain">
```

Comment: And changing it to post does not fix the problem.